# Correct Usage of Nigh in a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Currently, I am trying to come up with a poetic title involving *Nigh, Night, Ghost and Quiet*. However, I have struggled to figure out correctly where I can place Nigh in a sentence and be grammatically correct.

> Quietly Nigh Into the Ghostly Long Night of Solace

Comment: The "close or approaching" definition of "nigh"?

Comment: Death drew nigh in the ghostly quiet of the night.

Answer (score 2):

"Nigh" is defined as near, or almost. As in " It's nigh breakfast time", or "Breakfast time is nigh".

"Quietly Nigh Into the Ghostly Long Night of Solace" would be incorrect, as it's function as a reference for time doesn't make sense here, nor it's function as proximity.

Answer (score 2):

*Nigh, near, next* was the old degree paradigm.
You can see the final velar of the root memorialized in the `GH` of *nigh* and the /kst/ of *next*.

But:

> - Positive degree *nigh* became obsolete, and is considered archaic.
> - Comparative *near* reified as positive and regularized its paradigm: *near, nearer, nearest.*
> - Superlative *next* metaphorized from closest in (linear) space to closest in (future) time.

The most frequent usage of archaic terms is in fixed forms; *nigh* is not a productive word.
*Nigh unto,* for instance, matches an archaic *unto* with an archaic *nigh*. That would be OK.
But you shouldn't start the title with **both** *quietly* **and** *nigh unto*.

I'd recommend *Nigh Unto the Ghostly Long Night of Solace, Quietly*
if you feel you just have to use those words, for some reason.

Comment: That's a long title. I think I will remove quietly, simply for the sake of simplicity